# How can I put my program in the action list in android

Tags: android

When you want to share a file like the music file, if you have `telegram` and `viber` in your device you can choose one of these to share the music file. How can I do this? How can I add my program in the action list? What are the principles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android uses Intents for operations to be performed. Read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) for more information. 
For example to share an mp3 file you can start an Intent like this:

```
File recordingFile = new File(recording.getFilePath());
Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(recordingFile);
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
i.setType("audio/mp3");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUri);
try {
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share " + recording.getName()));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "There are no app installed to share your audio file.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```